# How to manipulate <script> tag using jQuery? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hey masters of jquery, i would like to ask if the script tag  of html can be manipulated by jquery. is it possible?

scenario :

i want to change the text "javascript/sqLite_dbController.js" to "javascript/gGears_dbController.js".

can anyone help me pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script has already been loaded when your code runs. So manipulation the script tag is pretty useless.